# Android Studio, the program does not run and instead a message box pops up

Tags: android, mobile

I ran a simple 'Hello-World' program on Android Studio. When I try to run the program, A window pops up labelled Android emulator with a mobile logo. A message box with save-quick-state pops up along with it.

Comment: share your java code

Comment: have you checked into the physical device?